# Javascript + JSON: кодирование данные в строку в формате UTF-8

Tags: javascript, json, кодировка, unicode

написал такой код:

```js
const text = JSON.stringify({
    text1: "english TEXT",
    text2: "русский ТЕКСТ",
    text3: "中文文本",
    text4: "english русский 本"
});

console.warn(text);
```

по которому получаю

```
{"text1":"english TEXT","text2":"Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ Ð¢Ð•ÐšÐ¡Ð¢","text3":"ä¸­æ–‡æ–‡æœ¬","text4":"english Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ æœ¬"}
```

подскажите пожалуйста, почему возникла проблема с кодировкой и как её можно исправить

1. Выделил этот код в отдельный html файл, получил ту же проблему
2. Пересохранил его как UTF-8 - проблема исчезла
3. Первоначальный файл - отправка запроса на сервер и файл уже в UTF-8 формате!!! Пересохранил еще раз как UTF-8, но проблема не исчезла

Подробнее:

Это React-проект, на сервер отсылается запрос через `fetch` и `JSON.stringify` указанных данных

Сервер отсылает данные обратно (ничего с ними не делая) и они приходят в указанном виде виде (со сбитой кодировкой)

Поэтому не знаю в чём дело - или в react-проекте или в кодировки файлов (с которыми работаю в Visual Studio Code, но там как раз в настройках стоит, что файлы в UTF-8) или в `fetch` или в `JSON.stringify` или в сервере :(

Comment: Где написали, где выполняете, где получаете? Больше подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: кажется разобрался - сам файл в котором я все это делаю был сохранен не в UTF8

Comment: , а нет - проблема осталась - дополнил свой вопрос данными

Comment: >"Сервер отсылает данные обратно (ничего с ними не делая) и они приходят в указанном виде виде (со сбитой кодировкой)", может код сервера приложите?

Comment: `data = sys.stdin.read(int(os.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))); return data['text1']`